# Angular change child path

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular so this might seem like an obvious question to some, but I can't seem to find the answer.
I have created some routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'steps', children: [
      {
        path: 'one', component: OneComponent, children: [
          {
            path: 'two', component: TwoComponent, children: [
              {
                path: 'three', component: ThreeComponent, children: [
                  { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and I have created a set of buttons to allow me to navigate these views:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['home']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Home</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/steps', 'one']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">One</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/steps', 'one', 'two']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Two</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/steps', 'one', 'two', 'three']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Three</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/steps', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'results']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Results</a>
```

They are working as expected. The only issue I have is the Url.
They are as follows:

- /steps/one
- /steps/one/two
- /steps/one/two/three
- /steps/one/two/three/results

I would like them to be:

- /steps/one
- /steps/two
- /steps/three
- /steps/results

But work in the exact same way they currently work.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'steps', children: [
    { path: 'one', component: OneComponent},
    {
        path: 'two', component: OneComponent, children: [
          {
            path: '', component: TwoComponent
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'three', component: OneComponent, children: [
          {
            path: '', component: TwoComponent, children: [
              {
                path: '', component: ThreeComponent
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'results', component: OneComponent, children: [
          {
            path: '', component: TwoComponent, children: [
              {
                path: '', component: ThreeComponent, children: [
                  { path: '', component: ResultsComponent }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    }

    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? as Children is an array of elements...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'steps', children: [
      { path: 'one', component: OneComponent },
      { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent },
      { path: 'three', component: ThreeComponent },
      { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: if I do it that way, two would replace one right? I am trying to create each "step" keep the content of the previous "step". So when on the results view, you can see all the content from one, two and three.

Comment: Yes, it replaces. I'm used to "keep the data" in a seperate service, not in components.